# Use one javascript variable into another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

**This is common.js**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var commonJs = {
        init: function () {
        },
        showAlert: function () {
        },

    }

});
```

**This is add.js**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var addJs = {
        init: function () {
            console.log(commonJs.showAlert);
        },
    }

});
```

I want to use common js function **commonJs.showAlert** in add.js

How can i access that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please simply place commonJs var outside the jQuery function and try again. It will work for you.

Comment: Thank you. It worked

Answer (score 0):

```
var commonJs;
jQuery(function ($) {

    commonJs = {
        init: function () {
        },
        showAlert: function () {
        },

    }

});
```

I just had to put this variable outside **jQuery(function ($)** and it worked.